# Настройка chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, диаграммы, chart.js

http://www.aevis.nl/portal/philips.html
Пожалуйста помогите настроить диаграмую
Zomm я добавил, а вот pan не работает, если отключаю зум начинает работать и наоборот. Т.е. работает либо зумм либо пан.
Нужно ещё сделать чтобы при клике на верхних кнопках шкала становилась от 30минут-1недели.

Comment: Добавь рабочий код в вопрос

Comment: http://www.aevis.nl/portal/philips.html

Comment: нарисуйте график в вопросе, напишите код здесь, там много чего другого есть в линке.

Comment: перейдите по этой сслке и увидит что там только график(диаграмма)

Comment: Перешел и вот результат `OOPS! THAT PAGE CAN’T BE FOUND.`.

Comment: http---://---www.aevis.nl/portal/philips.html

Comment: Уберите тире, сайт обрезал ссылку

Comment: Убедитесь что эту страницу вы открыли не только для админов, страница выдает 404

Comment: http://dropmefiles.com/TMK9A Вот архив полный с файлами

Comment: хорошо посмотрю и скажу вам что получилось

Comment: Что-нибудь получается?